# database writes need to be verified in an integration test?

Tags: testing, jestjs, integration, typeorm, nest

I basically have an api that writes to 2 different tables, and am using `supertest` to make api calls to write a certain data to the database e.g. `POST /userCertificates` writes his address in the address table, education in status table like so:

I basically do this as one of the integration tests:

```
payload = {user_id: 1, name: abc, address: {a: x, b: y}, education: {a: x, b: y} ...}

it('Post to the database'), ()=>{
request.post(/userCertificate).send(payload).expect(200)
.then(res => 
   expect(payload.userAddress).toEqual(res.body.userAddress)
   // more expects to verify the response received)
}
```

The /userCertificates api basically does this:

- creates a new user with `name` and `user_id`
- saves data of address to the address table and establishes FK relation.
- saves data of education to the education table and establishes FK
  relation.

But, the real confusion is, do I also need to use a `dao layer` that directly talks with the database to absolutely verify that the data has been written to the 2 tables? E.g.
for my case above(in the same `describe` block):

*NOTE: user_id is a foreign key in the address and education table*

```
 it('Verify data written to the address table', ()=> {
   const data = AddressDao.find({user_id: 1})
    if(data.length <= 0) { 
      throw 'Data not written to the database
    }
  } 

 it('Verify data written to the education table', ()=> {
   const data = EducationDao.find({user_id: 1})
    if(data.length <= 0) { 
      throw 'Data not written to the database
    }
  }
```

But, not just in the case of writing to multiple tables, is such verification of data
written to the database required?